# Libconfigの使い方

Tags: c++

Linux Debian用にC++の簡単なアプリを書いています。

configファイルの読み書きに、Libconfig++を使おうと思うのですが、configファイルの読み込みはできるのですが、内容の更新のやり方が良く分かりません。
https://hyperrealm.github.io/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html

addメソッドは、新しい設定項目と値の追加ようですし、writeFileは有るのですが、値の更新のやり方が分かりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libconfig.h++>
using namespace std;
using namespace libconfig;

#define CONFIG_FILE "sample_conf"

int main()
{
    Config cfg;
    try{
        cfg.readFile( CONFIG_FILE );
    }
    catch(const FileIOException &fioex){
        cerr << "I/O error while reading file." << endl;
    }
    catch(const ParseException &pex){
        cerr << "Parse error at " << pex.getFile() << ":" << pex.getLine()
            << "-" << pex.getError() << endl;
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int start;
    int end;
    string file_name;

    try{
        if(!(cfg.lookupValue("start", start)))
            throw 1;
        if(!(cfg.lookupValue("end", end)))
            throw 2;
        if(!(cfg.lookupValue("file", file_name)))
            throw 3;

        cout << "Start" << '\t' << start << endl;
        cout << "End" << '\t' << end << endl;
        cout << "File Name" << '\t' << file_name << endl;
    }
    catch(int fError){
        cout << "Itme Error " << fError << endl;
    }

}
```

sample_conf

```
start = 10;
end = 20;
file = "settings";
```

＜追記＞

```
const Setting& root = cfg.getRoot();
const Setting& settings = root["settings"];

settings.lookupValue("start") = 30;
```

として見ましたが、エラーになります。

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
bool lookupValue(const char *, bool &)
bool lookupValue(const char *, int &)
bool lookupValue(const char *, unsigned int &)
.
.

Comment: settings["start"] = 30; で解決出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

> Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (bool value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (int value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (long value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (const long long &value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (float value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (const double &value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (const char *value)
>   Method on Setting: Setting & operator= (const std::string &value)

を使うのではないでしょうか？

```
cfg.lookup("start") = newValue;
```

Comment: lookupValueではエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: @saitoib 間違っていたので訂正しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: const Setting &root = getRoot();　　
root["start"] = 30;　　
で解決出来ました。
ありがとう、ございました。

Answer (score 1):

```
const Setting &root = getRoot();
root["start"] = 30;
```

で解決出来ました。ありがとうございました。

<sub>この回答は、[質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15090/saitoib)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51107/libconfig%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9#comment53359_51108)をコミュニティ wiki 回答として投稿したものです。</sub>